# How do I use jQuery/Javascript with jade template engine

Tags: javascript, jquery, pug

This is the code I have for the jade template so far

```
div
  -for(var group_key in data) {
    div.testsuite
      ul
        li(id="testsuite_#{group_key}") #{data[group_key][0].testsuite} (#{data[group_key][0].start_date})
          ul(id="testcases_#{group_key}")
            -for(var i = 0; i < data[group_key].length; i ++) {
              li(id="testcase_#{data[group_key][i].id}") #{data[group_key][i].name}
                ul(id="status_#{data[group_key][i].id}")
                  li Status: #{data[group_key][i].status}

                  #start here
                  -if(data[group_key][i].status == 'Pass') {
                    -document.getElementById(group_key).setAttribute("class", "pass")
                  -} else if (data[group_key][i].status == 'Incomplete') {
                    -document.getElementById(group_key).setAttribute("class", "incomplete")
                  -} else if (data[group_key][i].status == 'Fail') {
                    -document.getElementById(group_key).setAttribute("class", "fail")
                  -} else {

                  -}
                  #end here

                  li Time: #{data[group_key][i].time}
                  li Message: #{data[group_key][i].message}
                  li Time started: #{data[group_key][i].date}
            -}
  -}
```

What I'm trying to do from #start here and #end here is if the test case status equals 'Pass' set the class for li with the id of testsuite_#{group_key} to pass, else if it equals 'Incomplete', set the class to Incomplete, etc..

For the CSS, the pass class will have a background of green, incomplete = yellow, fail = red.

How would I accomplish this? See below

[image]

I'm currently getting an error using -document.getElementById.....
[image]

I tried using jQuery also but I still get an error.: -$.(group_key).addClass()

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the dash before `document.getElementById`. You only need dashes next to the actual if/then/else clauses, not the executing code. It's trying to find `-document` and is failing on that.

Comment: If I don't use dash before the document.getElementByid, the document becomes an html element <document group_key="" pass="" class="getElementById setAttribute true"></document>